# ERROR 1214 (HY000): The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes

Tags: mysql, sql

when I try below query am getting the error ERROR 1214 (HY000): The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes. I cannot understand this error. why it was occurs and how to resolve it

```
    MariaDB [appmgmt]> select * from employeedetails where match(empname) against('asd');
    ERROR 1214 (HY000): The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT   indexes
```

Comment: You have to define `fulltext` index on `empname` field.

Comment: I dont know how to  define fulltext index on empname field. can you modify the query and post over in comment? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL below version 5.6 then you can understand that `FULLTEXT` indexes can only be created on tables with the **MyIsam engine**.

Refer: [FullText Restrictions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-restrictions.html)